# PhoneGap application language

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, windows-phone

Is it possible to [configure](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml) the application language?

Answer (score 0):

With not absolute answer, Answer is no ( i cant see anything about language in docs).